# TypeError: leftMove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lts', and TypeError: rightMove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rts'

Tags: python

In this program, I have twelve turtles in my code (six on the left side, six on the right side). I created two functions that can make the user move one of the left turtle and one of the right turtle with a designated key press for the left turtle and the right turtle. When I tried to move my first turtle on the left side, I get this error message saying "TypeError: leftMove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lts'" when I try to move the first turtle on the left. I also get this error message while trying to move the first turtle on the right, saying "TypeError: rightMove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rts'" when I also try to move the first turtle on the right. How can I solve this error message so that the user can control the movement of both the first left and right turtles?

Here's my code:

```
import turtle as trtl

leftTurtles = [] #Stores the turtle from leftTurtleShapes    
rightTurtles = [] #Stores the turtle from rightTurtleShapes

leftTurtleShapes = ["triangle", "circle", "arrow", "square", "turtle", "classic"] 
rightTurtleShapes = ["classic", "square", "circle", "triangle", "arrow", "turtle"]
leftTurtleColors = ["gold", "silver", "dodgerblue", "greenyellow", "peru", "crimson"] #Color aligns with leftTurtleShapes
rightTurtleColors = ["dodgerblue", "peru", "gold", "crimson", "greenyellow", "silver"] #Color aligns with rightTurtleShapes

for d in leftTurtleShapes: #Makes the turtle of leftTurtleShapes and the color of leftTurtleColors to be aligned with leftTurtleShapes and be stored in leftTurtles
    lts = trtl.Turtle(shape=d)
    leftTurtles.append(lts)
    lts.penup()
    leftColor = leftTurtleColors.pop()
    lts.fillcolor(leftColor)
    lts.goto(-350, 0) #Moves the leftTurtle to the left side of the window
    lts.setheading(0)

for s in rightTurtleShapes: #Makes the turtle of rightTurtleShapes and the color of rightTurtleColors to be aligned with rightTurtleShapes and be stored in rightTurtles
    rts = trtl.Turtle(shape=s)
    rightTurtles.append(rts)
    rts.penup()
    rightColor = rightTurtleColors.pop()
    rts.fillcolor(rightColor)
    rts.goto(350, 0) #Moves the rightTurtle to the right side of the window
    rts.setheading(180)

def rightMove(rts): #User can control the movement of one of the right turtles
    rts.setheading(180)
    rts.forward(1)

def leftMove(lts): #User can control the movement of one of the left turtles
    lts.setheading(0)
    lts.forward(1)

rightMove(rightTurtles[0]) #User controls the first right turtle
leftMove(leftTurtles[0]) #User controls the first left turtle

wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.onkeypress(leftMove, "d") #User uses the letter "d" to control the movement of the left turtle
wn.onkeypress(rightMove, "e") #User uses the letter "e" to control the movement of the right turtle
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkeypress), the function cannot take any arguments.

So you can rewrite as:

```
def rightMove(): #User can control the movement of one of the right turtles
    rts = ... # set your turtle here
    rts.setheading(180)
    rts.forward(1)

def leftMove(): #User can control the movement of one of the left turtles
    lts = ... # set your turtle here
    lts.setheading(0)
    lts.forward(1)
```

Comment: But here's the thing: do I need to move my for loop statement into two of my functions for setting my turtle up? Because when I set my turtle up as rts = trtl.Turtle() and cleared my arguments, it wouldn't run. Also, it doesn't really make sense for my code to not take any arguments, because it wouldn't direct the program how and what the user is going to move both of the turtles. How would that help in the user moving the first left turtle and the first right turtle?

Comment: You can create a wrapper class for turtle and implement its own onpresskey.